# cURL not sending file data

Tags: linux, perl, curl, cgi

I have a cURL call that I'm trying to use to send file data to a remote server.

```
curl -X POST -u username:password -d 'data=@/path/to/file.ext&version=2&action=Parse' http://fqdn.to.server.i.control/Parser.cgi
curl -X POST -u username:password -d 'data=@localFile.ext&version=2&action=Parse' http://fqdn.to.server.i.control/Parser.cgi
cat file.ext | curl -X POST -u username:password -d 'data=@-&version=2&action=Parse' http://fqdn.to.server.i.control/Parser.cgi
```

The file contents are URI encoded already. Using Perl and CGI on the server side.

My problem is that when the server tries to access that "data" line, value I have is only "file.ext" - the path is stripped out and the file's contents are not used ($cgi->param("data") is just "file.ext", "localFile.ext" or "-" respectively).

Any indication as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you read the curl [man page](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)? The part after `-d` or `--data` needs to start with `@` in order to have a special behavior.

Comment: @MattJacob Holy crap. My local man page must be out of date. I did a google search for the man page and see this entry that isn't present in my local docs:

"name@filename

This will make curl load data from the given file (including any newlines), URL-encode that data and pass it on in the POST. The name part gets an equal sign appended, resulting in name=urlencoded-file-content. Note that the name is expected to be URL-encoded already."

It looks like my problem is the = I'm using. I feel so dumb, now.

Comment: @MattJacob Nevermind. That's for --data-urlencode. I read too far. 
I'll try a few more syntaxes when I am at my console again - Lots of this functionality says it was added after 7.13, my current version, so I may not even be able to do this.

Comment: You could still use shell commands, such as the following `bash` command: `-d "data=$( cat /path/to/file.ext )&version=2&action=Parse"`. Pretty sure that's valid `sh` too.

Comment: nobody should use such an old curl version as 7.13...

Answer (score 0):

@MattJacob was correct; my syntax was wrong. `data=@...` should have been `@...` and the `data=` portion should have been in the file. Boy am I thick.